# Android webview script tag not loading source web page

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm trying to load a webpage from a script tag in Webview, but it won't load it!

here's the source for the HTML Script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://google.com'></script>
```

Java Code:

```
WebView bannerWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.banner_webview1);
bannerWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
bannerWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

String html = "<html><head>"
                + "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src='http://google.com'></script>"
                + "</head>" + "<body>" + "</body>" + "</html>";

bannerWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: actually, if you put what u have in the string html in a html file it won't load it either.
What do you mean by "load a webpage from a script tag" ?

Comment: it means I am trying to load google.com within the script tag <script type=\"text/javascript\" src='http://google.com'></script>                                                                       but the link is suppose to load the java script code..

Comment: this is what your code does on a page, http://jsfiddle.net/UnwBF/
So the problem is in your html string

Answer (score -1):

Try this string:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src='http://www.google.com'></script>
</head>
</html>
```

and also check whether you are giving permission to access internet or not.